# WebBrowser перестал загружать динамичный контент

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Пишу парсер для soccerstand.com(спортивные события). Для получения информации со страниц использую webbrowser.
Всё работало нормально, но в один момент webbrowser перестал загружать результаты игр(вот пример страницы с результатами игр - https://www.soccerstand.com/match/0fm9jQMK/#h2h;overall) - висит бесконечная загрузка. Сперва подумал, что сайт ввёл какое-то ограничение для ie и подключил gecko к проекту, но результат оказался таким же. Декстопный Google Chrome и Firefox открывают страницу нормально, а декстопный ie так-же, как и webbrowser в проекте. 
В чем может быть проблема?
Спасибо!

Comment: Если вы в десктопном IE не можете увидеть сайт, то направляйте вопросы разработчикам сайта.

Comment: Подключите CefSharp и не мучайтесь, контрол для winforms у него имеется. По дефолту штатный контрол WebBrowser использует движок IE чуть ли не 6.0. Это можно изменить в реестре, даже где-то инструкции попадались, но зачем, когда можно сразу взять нормальный движок.

Comment: Я забыл это упомянуть, но я так и делаю - IE 6 версии, совсем не пригодный для использования браузер. Тут, похоже, дело не в браузере, потому что, вчера я подключил awesomium и получил результат, такой-же, как и в IE. И теперь у меня есть огромное подозрение, что подключив cefSharp, я опять увижу бесконечную загрузку.